# Spring JMSListener and JAXB marshalling

Tags: java, xml, spring, jaxb, spring-jms

i have a JMS "endpoint" like this:

```
@JmsListener(destination = "TestQueue")
public void doSomething(MyJaxbAnnotatedClass myclass) {
}
```

Of course with the needed applicationContext configuration like <jms:annotation-driven/> and the likes. All this worked when my method signature was only a

```
public void doSomething(String xmlString)
```

But i want to have automatic unmarshalling done by Spring like i do it with JSON in the Spring-MVC context. But somehow Spring needs more configuration for this to happen, because i get the following stacktrace when trying the MyJaxbAnnotatedClass parameter:

```
 Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: No converter found to convert to class de.xxx.xxx.MyJaxbAnnotatedClass, message=GenericMessage [payload=<BRNArtikelStamm:EcomxProducts 
xmlns:BRNfoo="http://www.xxx.xxx/foofoo"
```

So i assume i must somehow tell Spring how to unmarshal? Since JAXB is a pretty common way of doing serialization, i hope there is a common config which needs to be applied.

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to register a message converter that is able to do that, pretty much as you have to do for any non trivial conversion.

Since you're obviously using the default `JmsListerContainerFactory`, extend it to register a message converter for your listener, someething like:

```
@Bean
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    factory.setMessageConverter(jmsMessageConverter());
    return factory;
}
```

Your `jmsMessageConverter` defines how messages are deserialized (you can reuse the same instance on the produce side). Try `MarshallingMessageConverter` with `Jaxb2Marshaller`